# Obtaining shared drive creator through Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I need to find out the creator of all shared drives via the API with a service account but can't find a way to extract that info. I can get a list of all shares and can then get a list of the permissions related to each share but can't get the creator.

Am I missing something or is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike files in Drive, content in shared Drives is owner by a *group* of users.

There is no such thing as the "creator" of a Shared Drive. And there is no "owner" role allowed either.

See the docs [specific roles for shared Drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-shareddrives#specific_roles_for_shared_drives).

---

### Update:

When shared drives are created the API assigns the role of "organizer" to the creator. And then subsequent users or groups can be assigned the role of organizers too. I guess technically the creator is the first organizer to be assigned to the Drive. But there is no method to return the creator in Google Drive API at the moment.

Comment: Welllllll, you *say* that they don't have a creator but if you go to the GSuite section of the Google Admin tool and go to 'Manage Shared Drives', it quite clearly lists the creator of each drive. The data is most definitely there.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, but in Drive API there is no method to get the creator that you can see in https://admin.google.com/ac/drive/manageshareddrives

Comment: Yea, that's what I feared :(

Comment: Hmm.. You can use a Files->Get call on the ID of a drive to see who last *modified* a drive and, if the created timestamp is the same as the modified timestamp, then the last modifier must have been the creator. Seems about the only way and not very reliable.

Comment: Nope, ignore me. I can do a Files->Get on _my_ shared drives but not as a service account.

Comment: @Gaspode You can get the creator of the drive using the google drive audits from the reports API https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive#create, however this will only retain data for a max of 6 months.