# How to get the owner of the shared drive using GDrive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to find the owner of the shared drive items OR the organization name to which the shared drive belongs. How can I do that using GDrive API ?

Comment: Please refer to this one for the answer to your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63154777/obtaining-shared-drive-creator-through-google-drive-api